# pages of pdf file into variable

Tags: variable, pdf, echo

I have a problem with putting output of following instructions (instruction works) into variable:

```
pdftk file.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | awk '{print $2}'
```

when I do for example:

```
VARIABLE=$( pdftk file.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | awk '{print $2}' ) | echo $VARIABLE
```

it doesn't show me the value of variable... May somebody tell what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
; echo $VARIABLE
```

Instead of the last pipe.

Comment: This does answer the question.  It might be even more useful if you could expand on _why_ the pipe didn't work, in addition to pointing out the working alternative

Comment: ; means next command just as if you passed one command return then echo as a second one.   The pipe is not used for that

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$ VARIABLE=$( pdftk file.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | awk '{print $2}' ) ; echo "$VARIABLE"
```

The problem is to use a pipe (`|`) which doesn't work with echo.

Comment: Thank you a lot :D, such a stupid mistake which took from me more than hour :(

Comment: @Pamele Plese read [what should I do when someone answer my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to pipe `grep`'s output into `awk`.  awk can do the same kind of regular expression pattern matching as grep (and a lot more).
2. You need to double-quote variables when you use them.  And command substitutions.
3. As others have already pointed out, the pipe character doesn't terminate statements.  Use a new line or `;` instead.

Putting that all together:

```
VARIABLE="$(pdftk file.pdf dump_data | awk '/NumberOfPages/ {print $2}')"
echo "$VARIABLE"
```

---

BTW, `pdfinfo` from [poppler-utils](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) is another good tool for getting a summary of a PDF file's metadata (including the page count).  It gives you just the file metadata (title, subject, author, keywords, page count, etc) in an easily-parsed format without details about each individual page (so it's noticeably faster on large PDF files).

```
VARIABLE="$(pdfinfo file.pdf| awk '/Pages/ {print $2}')"
echo "$VARIABLE"
```